# How do I export emails to PDF without the "See More from..." history expanded at the end of the messages?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, pdf, file-conversion

I want to generate a PDF of an email correspondence. I don't want my PDF to include, at the end of each email, a quoted history of every message prior to it.

I open a conversation in Mail. I do not click the "See More from..." options i.e., don't expand them. The email looks the way I'd like it to in my PDF. I select every message in the conversation. I then choose File → Export to PDF  and save the file. I open the file and all the "See More from..." messages are expanded! I then have to go through the PDF manually and delete the unwanted pages.

Another option I've tried is printing the file to PDF, but a similar issue occurs. In that case, I can select which pages to print, rather than having to delete them after the export, but would rather the "See More from..." messages not be included in the first place.

How can I export the emails without the "See More from..." messages?

Comment: Why are you selecting every message in the conversation, when it sounds like you don't want to see them?

Comment: I want to see each message in order, like a correspondence, as opposed to a series of increasingly indented quotations in reverse order.